# How to Reset keymapping in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in the android development world. In the android studio, I just changed the default keymap (keyboard shortcuts). Is there any button to format to default keymap settings?

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL + ALT + S` -> `Keymap` -> `Settings` -> `Restore Defaults` or `Delete`

[image: android studio keymap settings]